# Chasing a OOM error with a .NET service

Tags: memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I'm just looking for some feedback or things I should check out... not really a definitive answer.

I am chasing an OOM error that is occurring with a .NET service. The service hovers around 1.3 GB for long periods of time. I realize this is a very large amount of memory but the service runs perfectly fine at this level for long periods of time (up to about  a month with no errors). Then it crashes sort of crashes randomly under normal operation.

I have been tracking the private bytes, bytes in all heaps, working set, and CPU usage for this service. When the issue happens the working set skyrockets from about 700 MB to 1.3 GB in about 30 seconds then the service crashes. When this happens the readings for the other (private bytes, bytes in all heaps, and CPU) freeze and stay **exactly** the same even though normally those three read slightly different numbers each time their values are updated.

This is sort of a weird situation for me. I have chased a few memory leaks before but this one is much different... anyone have any advice? Any thoughts, feedback, reflections are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how we can answer this without seeing some of your code.  If you are referring to a service you don't have the code for, your question is off-topic here.

Comment: I have the code but it is a massive amount of code... too much to put on here. I was hoping that the manner in which the service goes OOM might suggest an idea for someone. Like I said I am not looking for someone to give me a definitive answer just suggestions for possibilities or ways to diagnose the issue. You don't need to look at the code and find something and point it out. That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: My reflection: Run a profiler on it to see where it's using all that memory.

Answer (score 1):

The crash it should be creating a crash dump file. Open that with windbg and SOS, you should be able to get a stack trace of the steps leading to the exception. If no crash dump is being created you could install Debug Diagnostic tools and have it create the dump for you.